# Changing weight of font/button upon selection in react.js

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm using i18next for translating an interface.

```
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

function handleClick(lang) {
        i18n.changeLanguage(lang);
}
```

applied to two buttons.

```
<a onClick={ () => handleClick('en') }
   className="language-selector__link">EN</a>

<a onClick={ () => handleClick('de') }
   className="language-selector__link">DE</a>
```

How can I change the weight/bold of the selected language?
I tried to do something like this but it's not really working:

```
style={ handleClick ? { fontWeight:'800'} : {fontWeight : '400'} }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get current language

```
const current = i18next.languages[0];
```

Then in style

```
style={{ fontWeight: current === "en" ? 800 : 400}}
```